# Setting Database Type in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a product for my model that will go through a series of processing times. I'm assigning the processing times to each product type through an excel database which will be loaded into the model, with each processing time in a separate column (e.g. Product 1: 2.3, 4.8, 9 --> meaning that it takes 2.3-time units for process 1, 4.8-time units at process 2 and so on)

Currently, I am storing all the processing time in a List(Double) within my product (e.g. v_ProcessTime = [2.3, 4.8, 9]). However, I face an error when some columns contain purely integers instead of double values (The column value type will be recognised as integers and Anylogic prompts an error that I can't write an integer to a double list). The only workaround currently is to change the column type of the database to Double values manually.

Is it possible to use Java coding to change the value type of databases or any way to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, how the database recognize the type is out of your control... and yeah if you can't change the source itself with at least 1 value that is not an integer, then your only choice is to change the database value manually.

nevertheless, to use them in a list, you can just transform an integer into a double like this

```
(double)intVariable
```